# Как внести чистый svg в html? (svg кнопка)

Tags: html, html5, svg

Конвертировал картинку в `svg`, нужно теперь её всунуть в код сайта. Но не ссылкой, а чистым кодом. Нужно всунуть сюда:

```
<input type="image" src="">
```

Как это сделать? И что именно из этого нужно вставить?

svg :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="500">
<circle cx="250" cy="250" r="210" fill="#fff" stroke="#000" stroke-width="8"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: не понятно чего Вы добиваетесь, какой результат визуально Вы хотите?

Comment: Я хочу получить кнопку в виде картинки. Но я не могу использовать ссылку на картинку, она должна быть внедрена в саму html страницу, поэтому само изображение я пытаюсь вывести в svg.

Comment: событие клика можно привязать на любой элемент, svg можно вставить как отдельные теги или как background к элементу

Comment: Вам просто нужно Svg кнопка?

Comment: Да, просто кнопка

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот так может выглядеть простейшая Svg кнопка

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('click')
})
```

```css
circle {
  transition: 200ms;
  cursor: pointer;
}

circle:hover {
  fill: steelblue
}

circle:active {
  r: 240;
}

text {
  text-anchor: middle;
  dominant-baseline: central;
  font-size: 200px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<svg id=button viewbox=0,0,500,500 width="50px" height="50px">
  
  <circle cx="250" cy="250" r="210" fill="#fff" stroke="#000" stroke-width="8"/>
  <text x="250" y="250"></text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Автор имел ввиду конвертировать `svg` в `base64` и подставить в `type="image"`, но всё равно хорошо